# How to trigger a upgrade service when new version deployed with spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

If my application would be versioned from 1.0 to 2.0.

When my application (2.0) deploys, how could I run some upgrade methods when detected version change from spring boot?

I try to add my upgrade service here

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(VersaECPApplication.class, args);
        if(upgrading){
            MyUpgradeService.run(); // HERE
        }
    }
```

It might work, but is there any proper way through spring framework to trigger upgrade services?

Comment: If it is related to database script upgrade you can look at [LiquiBase](https://www.liquibase.org/) or [FlyWay](https://flywaydb.org/).

Comment: What will the upgrade services do? I'm not aware of any spring features specific for this purpose but you can listen to application context events with `@EventListener`, which is probably a better way to start arbitrary tasks than your posted code.